# Phantom stderr error, when running local prerender?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, prerender

I have installed Phantom.JS and add it to the windows env.path.
When I type `phantomjs`, phantom console shows up.

I have also cloned Prerender.io [repository](https://github.com/prerender/prerender), and ran `npm install`.

When I tried to run it with `node server.js`, I get the following error:

```
2015-04-24T13:11:12.710Z phantom crashed, restarting...
2015-04-24T13:11:12.710Z starting phantom on port [12301]
phantom stderr: 'C:\Users\Mykhaylo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

**Why am I getting this error?

How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting PhantomJS to a path that doesn't have spaces and/or move your project to a path that doesn't have spaces